# Is there a fast way to manipulate and buffer a screen in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, buffer

I am working on a game for learning purposes, I want to make it only  with the .NET-Framework and a Windows Forms project in C#.

I want to get the 'screen' (Something that can be displayed on the window) as an `int[]`. Modify the array and reapply the altered array to the 'screen' in a buffered manner (So that it doesn't flicker).

I am currently using a `Panel`, which I draw a `Bitmap` on with `Graphics`. The `Bitmap` is converted to an `int[]` which I then can modify and reapply to the `Bitmap` and redraw. It works, but is very slow, especially because I have to scale up the image every frame because my game is only 300x160 and the screen 900x500.

Build up:

```
    // Renders 1 frame
    private void Render()
    {    
        // Buffer setup
        _bufferedContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        _buffer = _bufferedContext.Allocate(panel_canvas.CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, _scaledWidth, _scaledHeight));

        _screen.clear();

        // Get position of player on map
        _xScroll = _player._xMap - _screen._width / 2;
        _yScroll = _player._yMap - _screen._height / 2;

        // Indirectly modifies the int[] '_pixels'
        _level.render(_xScroll, _yScroll, _screen);
        _player.render(_screen);

        // Converts the int[] into a Bitmap (unsafe method is faster)
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* intPtr = &_screen._pixels[0])
            {
                _screenImage = new Bitmap(_trueWidth, _trueHeight, _trueWidth * 4, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(intPtr));
            }
        }

        // Draw generated image on buffer
        Graphics g = _buffer.Graphics;
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        g.DrawImage(_screenImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 900, 506));

        // Update panel buffered
        _buffer.Render();
    }
```

Is there a faster way without external libraries to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure about the unsafe code , But I do know about the buffered graphics manager. I think you should create a class for it instead of creating a new one every time.As well as having all of your sprites widths and heights be determined at the load instead of scaling them. That sped up my small game engine a good bit.

```
class Spritebatch
{
    private Graphics Gfx;
    private BufferedGraphics bfgfx;
    private BufferedGraphicsContext cntxt = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;

    public Spritebatch(Size clientsize, Graphics gfx)
    {
        cntxt.MaximumBuffer = new Size(clientsize.Width + 1, clientsize.Height + 1);
        bfgfx = cntxt.Allocate(gfx, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, clientsize));
        Gfx = gfx;
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        bfgfx.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
    }

    public void Draw(Sprite s)
    {
        bfgfx.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(s.Texture, new Rectangle(s.toRec.X - s.rotationOffset.Width,s.toRec.Y - s.rotationOffset.Height,s.toRec.Width,s.toRec.Height));
    }

    public void drawImage(Bitmap b, Rectangle rec)
    {
        bfgfx.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(b, rec);
    }

    public void drawImageClipped(Bitmap b, Rectangle rec)
    {
        bfgfx.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(b, rec);
    }

    public void drawRectangle(Pen p, Rectangle rec)
    {
        bfgfx.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
    }

    public void End()
    {
        bfgfx.Render(Gfx);
    }

}
```

This is a example of what I used. It's set up to mimic the Spritebatch in Xna. Drawing the images Unscaled will really increase the speed of it.Also creating one instance of the buffered graphics and Context will be faster then creating a new one every time you have to render. So I would advise you to change the line g.DrawImage(_screenImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 900, 506)); to DrawImageUnscaled(_screenImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 900, 506));

Edited : Example of how to scale code on sprite load

```
    public Sprite(Bitmap texture, float x, float y, int width, int height)
    {
        //texture is the image you originally start with.

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
        // Create a bitmap with the desired width and height
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.DrawImage(texture, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        // get the graphics from the new image and draw the old image to it
        //scaling it to the proper width and height
        Texture = b;
        //set Texture which is the final picture to the sprite.
        //Uppercase Texture is different from lowercase
```

Comment: I have to scale the image, because my game is only 320x160 pixels big and I want to scale it up so it fits to the screen of the user.

Comment: @Berntonline I know that you will probably need to scale the images. I do for my game as well. What you need to do is scale them in the beginning. For example :

Comment: Well, I have a new image every frame, so I have to scale them up everytime, haven't I?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling of the image is expensive enough, even when is done without any interpolation. To speed up the things, you should minimize memory allocations: when you create brand new Bitmap every frame, it leads to object creation and pixmap buffer allocation. This fact negates all the benefits you get from BufferedGraphics. I advise you to do the following:

1. Create the Bitmap instance of required size (equal to screen size) only once, outside of Render method.
2. Use direct access to bitmap data through [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, and try to implement the scaling be hand using nearest pixel.

Of course, using some sort of hardware acceleration for scaling operation is the most preferred option (for example, in opengl all images are usually drawn using textured rectangles, and rendering such rectangles implicitly involves the process of "scaling" when texture sampling is performed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why do you call this "very slow", because I did some tests and the performance doesn't seem bad. Also have you measured the performance of your rendering code into `int[] '_pixels'` (unfortunately you haven't provided that code) separately from the bitmap operations, because it might be the slow part.
About your concrete question. As others mentioned, using preallocated buffered graphics and bitmap objects would speed up it a bit.
But do you really need that `int[]` buffer? `BufferedGraphics` is already backed internally with a bitmap, so what really happens is:

(1) You fill the `int[]` buffer
(2) `int[]` buffer is copied to the new/preallocated `Bitmap`
(3) `Bitmap` from step 2 is copied (applying scale) to the `BufferedGraphics` internal bitmap (via `DrawImage`)
(4) `BufferedGraphics` internal bitmap is copied to the screen (via `Render`)

As you can see, there are a lot of copy operations. The intended usage of `BufferedGraphics` is:

(1) You fill the `BufferedGraphics` internal bitmap via drawing methods of the `BufferedGraphics.Graphics` property. If setup, the `Graphics` will do the scaling (as well other transformations) for you.
(2) `BufferedGraphics` internal bitmap is copied to the screen (via `Render`)

I don't know what your drawing code is doing, but if you can afford it, this definitely should provide the best performance.

Here is my quick and dirty test in case you are interested in:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    enum RenderMode { NewBitmap, PreallocatedBitmap, Graphics }
    class Screen
    {
        Control canvas;
        public Rectangle area;
        int[,] pixels;
        BitmapData info;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BufferedGraphics buffer;
        float scaleX, scaleY;
        public RenderMode mode = RenderMode.NewBitmap;
        public Screen(Control canvas, Size size)
        {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            var bounds = canvas.DisplayRectangle;
            scaleX = (float)bounds.Width / size.Width;
            scaleY = (float)bounds.Height / size.Height;
            area.Size = size;
            info = new BitmapData { Width = size.Width, Height = size.Height, PixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, Stride = size.Width * 4 };
            pixels = new int[size.Height, size.Width];
            bitmap = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, info.PixelFormat);
            buffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(canvas.CreateGraphics(), bounds);
            buffer.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            ApplyMode();
        }
        public void ApplyMode()
        {
            buffer.Graphics.ResetTransform();
            if (mode == RenderMode.Graphics)
                buffer.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
        }
        public void FillRectangle(Color color, Rectangle rect)
        {
            if (mode == RenderMode.Graphics)
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
                    buffer.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            }
            else
            {
                rect.Intersect(area);
                if (rect.IsEmpty) return;
                int colorData = color.ToArgb();
                var pixels = this.pixels;
                for (int y = rect.Y; y < rect.Bottom; y++)
                    for (int x = rect.X; x < rect.Right; x++)
                        pixels[y, x] = colorData;
            }
        }
        public unsafe void Render()
        {
            if (mode == RenderMode.NewBitmap)
            {
                var bounds = canvas.DisplayRectangle;
                using (var buffer = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(canvas.CreateGraphics(), bounds))
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    fixed (int* pixels = &this.pixels[0, 0])
                        bitmap = new Bitmap(info.Width, info.Height, info.Stride, info.PixelFormat, new IntPtr(pixels));
                    buffer.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                    buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, bounds);
                    buffer.Render();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (mode == RenderMode.PreallocatedBitmap)
                {
                    fixed (int* pixels = &this.pixels[0, 0])
                    {
                        info.Scan0 = new IntPtr(pixels); info.Reserved = 0;
                        bitmap.LockBits(area, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly | ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer, info.PixelFormat, info);
                        bitmap.UnlockBits(info);
                    }
                    buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, canvas.DisplayRectangle);
                }
                buffer.Render();
            }
        }
    }
    class Game
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var game = new Game();
            game.Run();
        }
        Form form;
        Control canvas;
        Screen screen;
        Level level;
        Player player;
        private Game()
        {
            form = new Form();
            canvas = new Control { Parent = form, Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 900, 506) };
            form.ClientSize = canvas.Size;
            screen = new Screen(canvas, new Size(300, 160));
            level = new Level { game = this };
            player = new Player { game = this };
        }
        private void Run()
        {
            bool toggleModeRequest = false;
            canvas.MouseClick += (sender, e) => toggleModeRequest = true;
            var worker = new Thread(() =>
            {
                int frameCount = 0;
                Stopwatch drawT = new Stopwatch(), applyT = new Stopwatch(), advanceT = Stopwatch.StartNew(), renderT = Stopwatch.StartNew(), infoT = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                while (true)
                {
                    if (advanceT.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3)
                    {
                        level.Advance(); player.Advance();
                        advanceT.Restart();
                    }
                    if (renderT.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 8)
                    {
                        frameCount++;
                        drawT.Start(); level.Render(); player.Render(); drawT.Stop();
                        applyT.Start(); screen.Render(); applyT.Stop();
                        renderT.Restart();
                    }
                    if (infoT.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000)
                    {
                        double drawS = drawT.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0, applyS = applyT.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0, totalS = drawS + applyS;
                        var info = string.Format("Render using {0} - Frames:{1:n0} FPS:{2:n0} Draw:{3:p2} Apply:{4:p2}",
                            screen.mode, frameCount, frameCount / totalS, drawS / totalS, applyS / totalS);
                        form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => form.Text = info));
                        infoT.Restart();
                    }
                    if (toggleModeRequest)
                    {
                        toggleModeRequest = false;
                        screen.mode = (RenderMode)(((int)screen.mode + 1) % 3);
                        screen.ApplyMode();
                        frameCount = 0; drawT.Reset(); applyT.Reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.IsBackground = true;
            worker.Start();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        class Level
        {
            public Game game;
            public int pos = 0; bool right = true;
            public void Advance() { Game.Advance(ref pos, ref right, 0, game.screen.area.Right - 1); }
            public void Render()
            {
                game.screen.FillRectangle(Color.SaddleBrown, new Rectangle(0, 0, pos, game.screen.area.Height));
                game.screen.FillRectangle(Color.DarkGreen, new Rectangle(pos, 0, game.screen.area.Right, game.screen.area.Height));
            }
        }
        class Player
        {
            public Game game;
            public int x = 0, y = 0;
            public bool right = true, down = true;
            public void Advance()
            {
                Game.Advance(ref x, ref right, game.level.pos, game.screen.area.Right - 5, 2);
                Game.Advance(ref y, ref down, 0, game.screen.area.Bottom - 1, 2);
            }
            public void Render() { game.screen.FillRectangle(Color.Yellow, new Rectangle(x, y, 4, 4)); }
        }
        static void Advance(ref int pos, ref bool forward, int minPos, int maxPos, int delta = 1)
        {
            if (forward) { pos += delta; if (pos < minPos) pos = minPos; else if (pos > maxPos) { pos = maxPos; forward = false; } }
            else { pos -= delta; if (pos > maxPos) pos = maxPos; else if (pos < minPos) { pos = minPos; forward = true; } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The operations with 'pixels' aren't taking much, I tested that.